# ttyUSB not available in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: tty

I want to write a basic serial pc to  usb communication program in linux,for this purpose i listed all the files under dev.I am not able to find ttyUSB.
what should i do?.please do help me as i am new to ubuntu

Comment: Is a suitable device actually plugged in?

Comment: actually i had not..i didnt know that before.now i am able to access it.thank you